# Proof of asymptotical relation of sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\left \{ a_n \right \}_n$ and $\left \{ b_n \right \}_ n$ be positive sequences.

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ exists and is not equal to zero, then there exists $k>0$, for any n large enough $$kb_{n}<a_{n}<2kb_{n}$$
I began the prove by unpacking the definition of limit for sequence, that is $\exists L \in \mathbb{R^{+}}, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists n_{0} \in \mathbb{N} s.t. \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq n_{0} \implies \left | \frac{a_n}{b_n} - L  \right | < \epsilon $, continued it with $$L-\epsilon < \frac{a_n}{b_n} < L+ \epsilon \\
b_n(L-\epsilon) < a_n < b_n(L+ \epsilon) \\ $$
I thought that it would be reasonable to pick $L=1.5$ and $\epsilon = 0.5$, as they pertain assumption, but I am not sure if this is correct way for showing that this equation holds for $k>0$ .
Any suggestions?

Comment: You can choose the $\varepsilon$ however you desire, but you can't pick the $L$!

Comment: Hint: take $k := L - \varepsilon$, and adjust the $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @BrunoB thanks for the clarification, can the equation be justified if making $\epsilon$ dependent on L? for example $\epsilon = L$ to show that the right-hand side of the inequality holds?

Comment: Yes you can make the $\varepsilon$ depend on $L$ (and you'll have to).

Comment: @BrunoB you mentioned that $\epsilon$ should be adjusted, this adjustment should hold for only the left-hand side of inequality? Since $K< \frac{x_n}{y_n}$ already holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L > 0$ be the limit of the sequence $\left( \frac{a_n}{b_n} \right)_n$.
Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Consider $k :=  L - \varepsilon$. We have, for all $n$ above a big enough $N_\varepsilon$:
$$kb_n < a_n < (k + 2\varepsilon)b_n$$
It therefore suffices to find $\varepsilon$ such that $k > 0$ and $k + 2\varepsilon \leq 2k$, and we'll be done (this is what I meant by "adjusting $\varepsilon$" in the comments).
But: $$k + 2\varepsilon \leq 2k \,\Leftrightarrow\, L + \varepsilon \leq 2(L - \varepsilon) \,\Leftrightarrow\, \varepsilon \leq \frac{L}{3}$$
Hence we can take $\varepsilon := \frac{L}{3}$ (the condition $k > 0$ being fulfilled because $\frac{L}{3} < L$).

---

The same method will of course let you find an adequate $\varepsilon$ for any given $\alpha > 0$, such that there exists $k > 0$ such that, for all $n$ big enough: $$kb_n < a_n < k(1 + \alpha)b_n$$